# Difference in dates of two columns and automatically updating it in third column

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider there are two columns named `StartDate`,`EndDate`(`2017/03/09 11:25:02`, `2018/08/10 15:20:03`) in `sql`.

I need to get the `DurationDate` column(number of `years`, `months`, `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds`) should be automatically updated in the duration column based on `StartDate` and `EndDate` in the `sql` table.

Comment: Create a view, to always return up-to-date values!

Comment: Create a trigger that executes on update and on insert of each of the columns.

Answer (score 3):

Since Oracle 11g, you can use generated columns:

```
alter table t add duration as (EndDate - StartDate);
```

This will produce an interval result if the two "dates" are stored as `timestamps`.  The difference of two dates is a number of decimal days.

In earlier versions, you need to use views to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Tim has some great notes on VIRTUAL columns here https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1